# Scraping this URL, R XML and getting siblings

Tags: xml, r, xpath, web-scraping

Hi: I want to scrap the table Federal Electoral Districts – Representation Order of 2003 subtable "Ontario".  The URL is here: http://www.elections.ca/content.aspx?section=res&dir=cir/list&document=index&lang=e#list

I've tried this code and it gets me close, but not entirely there.

```
doc<-htmlParse('http://www.elections.ca/content.aspx?section=res&dir=cir/list&document=index&lang=e#list', useInternalNodes=TRUE)
doc2<-getNodeSet(doc, "//table/caption[text()='Ontario']")
```

I know I could use readHTMLTable to do this simply and just find the particular table, but I also want to know how to select the sibling nodes of the caption node that equals Ontario.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `following-sibling` in your XPATH:

```
library(XML)
appURL <- 'http://www.elections.ca/content.aspx?section=res&dir=cir/list&document=index&lang=e#list'
doc<-htmlParse(appURL, encoding = "UTF-8")
tableNode <- doc["//*[@id='list']/following-sibling::table/caption[text()='Ontario']/.."][[1]]
myTable <- readHTMLTable(tableNode)
> head(myTable)
Code          Federal Electoral Districts Population 2006
1 35001                       Ajax–Pickering         117,183
2 35002        Algoma–Manitoulin–Kapuskasing          77,961
3 35003 Ancaster–Dundas–Flamborough–Westdale         111,844
4 35004                               Barrie         128,430
5 35005                    Beaches–East York         104,831
6 35006                 Bramalea–Gore–Malton         152,698
```

So to break down the XPATH. The heading `Federal Electoral Districts – Representation Order of 2003` has an `id="list"`. id's in HTML are unique so we can filter on this

- `//*[@id='list']`
  Find the node with id equal to "list"
- `/following-sibling::table`
  Get all its sibling nodes that follow it that are tables
- `/caption[text()='Ontario']`
  Select the nodes that have caption with text equals "Ontario"
- `/..`
  Go back a node

This gives you the required table nodes as a list. There is only one node that satisfies the above requirements. This node can then be processed by `readHTMLTable`.

Comment: I somehow knew you'd be the one to answer this question

Comment: @RichardScriven a long time ago before XPATH existed I used to scrape HTML using regular expressions. When I discovered XPATH and what was once a fairly complex and brittle task was reduced to a couple of lines I was hooked. So now I always like an XPATH conundrum :).

Comment: This is really amazing, can you let me know what the best tutorial site is for xpathApply? I had no idea about the following-sibling::table syntax.